# Box2d - Problems calculating impulse with speed and angle

Tags: c++, box2d, physics

I have a weapon that bounces to the next enemy when it hits.

I first begin by calculating the delta and the getting the angle:

```
float deltaX = e->m_body->GetPosition().x - m_body->GetPosition().x;
float deltaY = e->m_body->GetPosition().y - m_body->GetPosition().y;

float angle = atan2((deltaY), deltaX) * 180 / M_PI;
```

Then I convert the angle to a vector and multiply it by 15 (the speed of the projectile):

```
b2Vec2 vec = b2Vec2(cos(angle*M_PI/180),sin(angle*M_PI/180));
vec *= 15.0f;
```

Finally, I apply the impulse to the body:

```
m_body->ApplyLinearImpulse(vec, m_body->GetPosition());
```

The problem is that the vector must be incorrect as the bullet does not go in the right direction. If I simply output the angle to the next enemy, it tends to output an angle that looks correct so the problem must be in the conversion to a vector.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use any trigonometry functions here, because you already have the direction:

```
b2Vec2 direction = e->m_body->GetPosition() - m_body->GetPosition();
direction.Normalize(); // this vector now has length 1

float speed = ...;
m_body->ApplyLinearImpulse( speed * direction, m_body->GetWorldCenter() );
```